# meteor spacebars, sending data to the template

Tags: meteor, spacebars

```
<template name="add">
    {{> addst grName="{{name}}" }}  // tried without "" throwing error
      <div >{{name}}</div>  //Displaying the name
</template>
<template name="addst">
  {{grName}}           //Not working displaying {{name}}
</template>
```

why is the above code not working.

FYI, in the router I'm sending the data to add tempate

```
groups.findOne({_id:this.params._id}); in data context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax : no `""` nor `{{}}`.

```
<template name="add">
  {{> addst grName=name}}
  <div>{{name}}</div>
</template>

<template name="addst">
  {{grName}}
</template>
```